# Remove() function is not working in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, typeerror

Here I am trying to add and remove textboxes dynamically in my html. The textboxes are addes successfully but my remove function is not working

Please tell me why this function is  not working

```
  var counter = 2;
    $(document).ready(function () {

    $("#addButton").click(function () {
        if (counter > 5) {
            alert("Limit Exceeds");
            return false;
        }
        var $wrap = $('#TextBoxesGroup');
        var dynamichtml = '<div class="mcity"><label> Leaving from</label><input type="text" name="textbox' + counter + '" id="textbox' + counter + '" class="auto"/>  </div><div class="mcity"> <label> Going to</label>  <input type="text" name="textbox' + counter + '" id="textbox' + counter + 1 + '" class="auto"/> </div><div class="mcity"> <label> Going to</label>  <input type="text" name="textbox' + counter + '" id="textbox' + counter + 11 + '" class="auto"/> </div>';
        $wrap.append(dynamichtml);
        counter++;
    });

    $("#removeButton").click(function () {
        if (counter == 1) {
            alert("No more textbox to remove");
            return false;
        }

        counter--;
        $("#TextBoxesGroup").find("#divleft_" + counter).remove();
        $("#TextBoxesGroup").find("#divright_" + counter).remove();


    });
```

Comment: Please post your HTML becuase I can't find divLeft_ anywhere

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is My JSFiddle link

```
var counter = 1;
$(document).ready(function () {

$("#addButton").click(function () {
    if (counter > 5) {
        alert("Limit Exceeds");
        return false;
    }
    var $wrap = $('#TextBoxesGroup');
    var dynamichtml = "<div id='divleft_"+(counter)+"' ><div class='mcity' ><label> Leaving from</label><input type='text' name='textbox" + counter + "' id='textbox" + counter + "' class='auto'/>  </div><div class='mcity'> <label> Going to</label>  <input type='text' name='textbox" + counter + "' id='textbox"+ counter + 1 + "' class='auto'/> </div><div class='mcity'> <label> Going to</label>  <input type='text' name='textbox" + counter + "' id='textbox" + counter + 11 + "' class='auto'/> </div></div>";
    $wrap.append(dynamichtml);
    counter++;
});

$("#removeButton").click(function () {
    if (counter == 1) {
        alert("No more textbox to remove");
        return false;
    }
    counter--;
    $("#TextBoxesGroup").find("#divleft_" + counter).remove();
});
});
```

Comment: If any problem you may refer this link http://jsfiddle.net/UDq9W/
for html and remaining.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to achieve this

```
var counter = 1;


$("#addButton").click(function () {
    if (counter > 5) {
        alert("Limit Exceeds");
        return false;
    }
    var $wrap = $('#TextBoxesGroup');
    var dynamichtml = '<div class="box"><div class="mcity"><label> Leaving from</label><input type="text" name="textbox' + counter + '" id="textbox' + counter + '" class="auto"/>  </div><div class="mcity"> <label> Going to</label>  <input type="text" name="textbox' + counter + '" id="textbox' + counter + 1 + '" class="auto"/> </div><div class="mcity"> <label> Going to</label>  <input type="text" name="textbox' + counter + '" id="textbox' + counter + 11 + '" class="auto"/> </div></div>';
    $wrap.append(dynamichtml);
    counter++;
});

$("#removeButton").click(function () {
    if (counter == 1) {
        alert("No more textbox to remove");
        return false;
    }

    counter--;
    console.log(counter)
    $("#TextBoxesGroup div.box:last-child").remove();



});
```

Please check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fG5wV/)

Answer (score 0):

You are searching for ids that don't seem to exist.

```
$("#TextBoxesGroup").find("#divleft_" + counter).remove();
$("#TextBoxesGroup").find("#divright_" + counter).remove();
```

I think you probably just meant to wrap your dynamichtml in a `<div>` tag like this:

```
<div id='divleft_"+counter+"' >
```

Comment: Sorry, got called away while I was answering and it seems I was a bit late by the time I got back and submitted. But glad you've got your answer.

Comment: hahahaha dnt wry bro but i appreciate your answer too thanks for reply :)

Answer (score -1):

From the above question I understood and I developed this, check it once

```
[http://jsfiddle.net/UDq9W/][1]
```

Okay @Azad chouhan

Comment: Please post the code of your solution here, not that you understood the question.

Comment: My code is http://jsfiddle.net/UDq9W   in this fiddle.
Developed with id's and removing with ids

Comment: [That's the problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers). There's a reason [why you cannot link the fiddle](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/149890/prevent-posts-with-links-to-jsfiddle-and-no-code).

Comment: [Please read and understand](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/84345/183280). [Edit] the code in and I'll remove the downvote

Comment: So we should write the code fully here.
Well this will not be repeated.

Comment: It's Okay.
I'm not begging.
You have reputation,you may use for down vote or do any thing.
This will be for me
Thanks to Seniors.